# What caused Test of Spite to ban the Stronghold Builder's Guide?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

[A recent answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/174932/53359) introduced me to [Test of Spite](https://forums.giantitp.com/showsinglepost.php?p=8399975&postcount=2). After reading their rules, I found the following section shocking:

> - Iron Kingdoms material is allowed on a case by case basis.
> - Dragon and Dungeon Magazine are banned.
> - Serpent Kingdoms is approval-only material.
> - Savage Species is approval-only material.
> - Stronghold Builder's Guide is banned.

Do we know what caused them to ban the Stronghold Builder's Guide so completely? To my knowledge, Serpent Kingdoms and Savage Species are universally agreed to be hazardous for any DM to allow, so I'm amazed to see the Stronghold Builder's Guide listed as being banned even harder than they are.

Comment: This might be better asked at GiTP on that sub forum, as you may get an answer from one of the sheet screeners listed at the bottom right (I recognize TG Oskar from another forum on that site).

Comment: I play in a game with one of the people who ran ToS, so I’ll ask, see if he remembers. But most likely it’s because it’s an absurdly under-defined book that allowed The Cube to be built with one feat and regular mid-level WBL. And that feat and the rules it opens up are basically *the entire book*, so there’s just nothing left to approve (as opposed to *Serpent Kingdoms* which has a number of shockingly broken things, but also a ton of other crap that wouldn’t be a problem).

Comment: I voted to close this because it is an author-intent question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for designer reasoning.