# Can a Dweomerkeeper's Supernatural Spell Buff be dispelled?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic

The Dweomerkeeper has the supernatural ability Supernatural Spell that turns a spell into a supernatural effect. In the description, the relevant part is

> The spell functions as it normally would and is expended normally, but
> the dweomerkeeper does not require any components, does not provoke
> attacks of opportunity, and ignores the target's spell resistance,
> just as if she were using a supernatural ability instead of a spell.

Does this mean, that a Haste spell for example, cast as a Supernatural Spell would not be subject to dispel magic?
Or does "The spell functions as it normally would" part mean, that the effect of the (supernatural) spell is a normal ongoing spell effect that can be dispelled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No, it can't be dispelled.

The Dweomerkeeper's *Supernatural Spell* class feature states (*More Divinity* web enhancement for *Complete Divine*, page 2):

> At 4th level, **the dweomerkeeper** is so attuned to the fabric of magic that she can manifest spell effects with almost no effort whatsoever. Once per day as a standard action, she **can use any one spell** with a casting time of up to 1 standard action **as a supernatural ability**. The spell chosen must be one that is currently available to the dweomerkeeper (that is, one that she has prepared or that she knows and has a spell slot of the appropriate level available to cast), but she can decide at the moment of casting to use this ability. **The spell functions** as it normally would and is expended normally, but the dweomerkeeper does not require any components, does not provoke attacks of opportunity, and ignores the target’s spell resistance, **just as if she were using a supernatural ability instead of a spell**. At every even-numbered level after the 4th, the dweomerkeeper gains one additional use of this ability per day.

And the [SRD](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#supernaturalAbilities) has this to say about Supernatural Abilities:

> Supernatural abilities are magical and go away in an antimagic field but are **not subject to** spell resistance, counterspells, or to **being dispelled by dispel magic**. [...]

Emphasis mine in both quotes.

The part that can cast some doubt is:

> The spell functions as it normally would and is expended normally, but the dweomerkeeper does not require any components, does not provoke attacks of opportunity, and ignores the target’s spell resistance, just as if she were using a supernatural ability instead of a spell.

Which only lists some of the benefits of the spell becoming a supernatural ability, but that doesn't mean it doesn't gain the unmentioned benefits, like not being able to counterspell or dispel it, because as stated before in the class feature the dweomerkeeper is casting the spell *as a supernatural ability*, thus gaining all of its benefits.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: A strict reading could have this ability be an exceptional kind of supernatural ability that follows *only* the rules of supernatural abilities that the ability itself describes. It might be worth putting forth that idea and refuting it. (Personally, I agree with this answer that the author here is describing in broad strokes the advantages of Su abilities generally, but it's hard to deny that there's absolutely no ambiguity.)

Comment: Disjunction may be worth mentioning. See the end of [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/58296/4563) for summary. If you play 3.pf, it may even be taken and used in a game.