# If X dispels Y, what if X or Y is not a spell or spell-like effect?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, class-feature, conditions

As I understand the intent, one can't, for example, be hasted and slowed at the same time no matter what. It should just result in normal state. Same for other effects that dispel (and, usually, also counter) each other.

Now what if it is (Ex) Haste vs (Su) Slow? Would they end each other as dispel would end corresponding spell effects? Maybe, they instead become suppressed, as Slow Breath suggests? Would it set a precedent, strong enough to rule all similar situations accordingly?

Maybe, it is helpful to consider them separately, each vs a spell effect?

Comment: [Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185516/can-a-dweomerkeepers-supernatural-spell-buff-be-dispelled)

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you could provide specific examples of this haste and slow.

Comment: @Fering Not really, unless the specific examples explicitly covered this case—in which case they’d be poor examples for this question.

Comment: @Fering I largely agree with the above, so I don't think examples should be included in the question. But if you are interested, I can give some: (Ex) Haste is from Swiftblade PrC [Haste Personified article](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/prc/20070327). (Su) Haste or Slow may come from Dweomerkeeper PrC (Complete Divine web enhancement "More Divinity", p. 1). (Su) slow effect also may come from Slow Breath ability of Dragonfire Adept (Dragon Magic, p. 24), and from a [Stone Golem](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/golem.htm#stoneGolem).

Comment: Why were my comments deleted from this question?

Comment: @MichaelDorf My guess is because you answered in comment which is afaik against both this and all SO policies.  Also not surprised if my comment reply to you gets deleted as it's off topic ;p  But 2 cents.

Comment: @joedragons I didn't answer anything though I just pointed out a few things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a rule in 3.5e that a specific rule trumps a general rule. You can find that rule in the *Rules Compendium*, on page 5, "Order of Rules Application."

There is a general rule that supernatural abilities cannot be dispelled, found on page 314 of the *Player's Handbook*:

> Supernatural abilities are not subject to dispelling, disruption or spell resistance.

(This is functionally different from the SRD version of the same rule, which only mentions *dispel magic*. The *PHB* rule is the correct one.)

However, there's a specific rule that the spell *haste* counters and dispels *slow*, and the spell *slow* counters and dispels *haste.* That means that any abilities that refer to either spell, like the stone golem's Slow ability that functions "as the spell," inherit those specific rules interactions and can thus be dispelled.

*Haste* and *slow*, specifically (unlike other spell pairs like *chill metal* and *heat metal* or *sympathy* and *antipathy*), get used almost as keywords. The Slow Breath breath ability, for example, doesn't slow its targets; it *slows* them. It then goes on to define what that means (it's exactly like the spell *slow*, which is purely coincedental according to the rules, except it suppresses *haste* rather than dispel it). Then there's something like the Blinding Speed feat from the *Epic Level Handbook*, which allows one to "act as if *hasted*." Rules-as-written, that doesn't do anything at all. *Hasted* isn't a term in 3.5. Immediately, that means DM calls are necessary; can Blinding Speed be dispelled? The rule about extraordinary abilities isn't a factor, here—this is clearly a much more specific interaction—but rather whether or not the spell *slow* can dispel *hasted* as well as *haste.* (We're disregarding that Blinding Speed is a free action to reactivate, so dispelling it isn't very useful.)

And then there's the Swiftblade's Fortified Hustle (Ex) ability, which says

> the effect becomes extraordinary rather than a continuous spell effect, and therefore cannot be dispelled by any means.

Is this just reminding us of a general rule, in which case *dispel magic* wouldn't work but *slow*'s specific dispelling clause would still take precedence, or is Fortified Hustle adding the weight of specificity to a Swiftblade's extraordinary *haste* spell? (It's worth pointing out that having *slow* take effect rather simply negate *haste* is pretty ruinous for a swiftblade, who can recast *haste* as a free action.) Again, this is up to your DM.

So the interaction between Ex or Su *slow* and *haste* will vary on a case-by-case basis, but for those instances that directly inherit the text of the spell *haste* and the spell *slow*, their specific dispel interaction is a much more specific rule than the general glossary definitions that says supernatural and extraordinary abilities can't be dispelled.

Comment: Could you expand on what a DM should actually do in those cases, how you would rule the subject? If you think it is inappropriate, I will acept your opinion on that, no problem.

Comment: @annoyingimp A list of how I would rule on all ways to get Ex or Su haste/slow would be outside the scope of this answer, but in general having them cancel is a hefty buff to haste. Haste gives an extra attack, but slow means you can't make full attacks so it doesn't matter; the other effects mostly cancel. I'm inclined to have them dispel: easier bookkeeping, rewards prepared players (like a ranger preparing a bunch of swift haste to fight a stone golem, for example), punishes persistent haste—this all seems fine. But does haste need the buff? That depends on the campaign's power level.